# columnar tree with orange caterpillar flowers identification

Tags: identification

I have a columnar tree about 7 feet tall and 1+ feet wide.  Leaves are long and thin.  It has interesting orange flowers (?) that are look like caterpillars on the branch.  There are no petals and they are made of tiny orange dots.  There are tiny white flowers elsewhere on the tree.  It may be a bush that is 7 feet tall.  Looking to see if anyone knows what this is. Thank you!!  chris[image]